# Java Piped Input/Output Stream massive delay in communication

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

I am making a java application that uses piped input/output streams (with a Object input/output stream wrapper around them). I was getting a pretty big delay when sending data over and thought it was because of my data's size initially. However the following demonstration shows the native delay in piped input/output streams when communicating on different threads.

```
public class Main{
public static long millis = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton button = new JButton("Press me");

    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream();
    PipedOutputStream pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);

    button.addActionListener(e -> {
        try {
            pos.write((int) (Math.random() * 1000));
            //records time the packet was sent
            millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    while (true) {
        System.out
                .println("recieved: " + pis.read() + "\n\tin time (ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - millis));
    }

}
```

}

This delay is usually around 300-900 ms for me. This is pretty big in my application. I am wondering why is it this big of a delay? And how can i fix my code to reduce the delay?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about flushing?

Comment: oh wow that is a silly mistake on my part, thanks for that hahaha.

Comment: It works now, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the output is not being flushed

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html#flush()